# Spring mvc register custom PropertyEditor

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, propertyeditor

Let's say we have:

class Car:

```
public class Car{
   private String model;
   private String brand;
   private Collection<People> owners;

   //constructor,getters and setters
}
```

Class People:

```
public class People{
   private Car car;
   private String name;
   private Gender gender;

   //constructor,getters and setters
}
```

Class Gender:

```
public class Gender{
   private Char gender;

   //constructor,getters and setters
}
```

---

Then if i want to pass the collection owners to my view:

```
<body>
        <h1>Car detail: </h1>
        <h2>Owners: </h2>
        <table>
            <form:form modelAttribute="owners" method="post" action="processOwnersSelection.htm">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <ul>
                            <form:checkboxes element="li" path="owners" items="${owners}"></form:checkboxes>
                        </ul>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <button type="submit">Next</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </form:form>
        </table>               
    </body>
```

By my Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/selectOwners")
    protected ModelAndView showOwnersSelection() throws ServiceException{
        return new ModelAndView("car/ownerSelection", "owners", super.getService().getAllOwners());
    }
```

*Note.* This will be used to connect multiple owners (who existe in out DB) to a car.

i'll get an error:

> org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid
>   property 'owners' of bean class [java.util.HashMap$Values]: Bean
>   property 'owners' is not readable or has an invalid getter method:
>   Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the
>   setter?

---

As far as I understand Spring converts these by using implamentations of PropertyEditor or Converter ?

So I should manually write one, but then how will Spring know i made one he(or she) has to use ? And how should one look like ?

Comment: can you show how you are using at view side ?

Comment: edited like requested....

Comment: You don't need PropertyEditor or Converter for this. PropertyEditor  and Converter is used for advanced type conversion and not for simple types. What is owner here (I couldn't see Owner class) and which field in Owner you want to display in Checkbox?

Comment: owners is the name of the collection in the Car class, `Collection<People> owners;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring 3 Type Converter SPI supercedes JavaBean PropertyEditors.

`<mvc:annotation-driven />` in the configuration file will automatically install default type converters. We can override defaults with annotations such as @DateTimeFormat or @NumberFormat.

For custom field types, we can follow below convention over configuration:

1. Define a static valueOf(String) method or Constructor(String) to parse your value from its String representation
2. Implement toString() to print your value for display

See [this link](http://spring.io/blog/2009/11/17/spring-3-type-conversion-and-validation/) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

see always

```
 <form:form modelAttribute="owners" method="post" 
  action="processOwnersSelection.htm">
```

modelAttribute should be the reference name of object which holds all the peroperties coming under its form .

and we can access them using path attribute of spring tag like checkboxes or whaever.

I am assusing you are using `owners` as modelAttribute and which might not be a model of `People` class inside your controoler.

i don't know how you defined it in controller.

i think you must use `People` reference model attribute instead of `owners` in below code

```
 <form:form modelAttribute="owners" method="post" 
      action="processOwnersSelection.htm">
```

because `path="owners"` it tries to find `owners` attribute inside a class you defined for `modelAttribute="owners"` inside controller.

please check it properly.

Comment: `return new ModelAndView("car/ownerSelection", "owners", super.getService().getAllOwners());`

Comment: that is how i come to this view, so nope I'm passing "owners" as modelAttribute

Comment: hey i am talking about modelAttribute="owners" inside form:form, it should always match the bean means class

Comment: As far as i understand the modelAttribute in my form:form must match with the attribute that i provide to the model in my controller, so the form knows where to send the data to @submission ?

Comment: no boss..always the modelAttribute in my form:form must be the bean , it can also be termed as commandName which you can use alternatively for modelAttribute ....moreover when you use path for checkbox or input you know right how it binds like with bean ?

Comment: I suspect the problem is with the path in my <checkboxes ...>, Sprive will look for a setowners(...) class in the default converter or PropertyEditor. I don't Know....